# Normalizing columns of matrix between -1 and 1

Tags: r, matrix, normalization

I have a large matrix (thousands of rows and hundreds of lines) which I'd like to normalize column-wise between -1 and 1. This is the code I wrote:

```
normalize <- function(x) { 
    for(j in 1:length(x[1,])){
        print(j)
        min <- min(x[,j])
        max <- max(x[,j])
        for(i in 1:length(x[,j])){
            x[i,j] <- 2 * (x[i,j] - min)/( max - min) - 1
        }
    }
    return(x)
}
```

Unfortunately it waaaay to slow. I've seen this:

```
normalize <- function(x) { 
    x <- sweep(x, 2, apply(x, 2, min)) 
    sweep(x, 2, apply(x, 2, max), "/") 
}
```

It's fast but it normalizes between 0 and 1. Can you help me please modifying it for my purpose? 
I'm sorry but I'm at the beginning learning R

Comment: First write some tests so that you can be sure your slow code is giving the right answer. Then you can check all the "solutions" about to be splatted onto SO do what you want. Writing tests is fun!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about rescaling the matrix `x` at the end of your own function?

```
normalize <- function(x) { 
    x <- sweep(x, 2, apply(x, 2, min)) 
    x <- sweep(x, 2, apply(x, 2, max), "/") 
    2*x - 1
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Benchmarks:

```
normalize2 <- function(A) { 
  scale(A,center=TRUE,scale=apply(A,2,function(x) 0.5*(max(x)-min(x))))
}

normalize3 <- function(mat) { 
  apply(mat,2,function(x) {xmin <- min(x); 2*(x-xmin)/(max(x)-xmin)-1})
}

normalize4 <- function(x) { 
  aa <- colMeans(x)
  x <- sweep(x, 2, aa)           # retrive the mean from each column

  2* sweep(x, 2, apply(x, 2, function(y) max(y)-min(y)), "/") 
}


set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix(sample(1:10,1e5,TRUE),1e3)
erg2 <- normalize2(mat)
attributes(erg2) <- attributes(normalize3(mat))
all.equal(  
  erg2,  
  normalize3(mat),   
  normalize4(mat)
  )

[1] TRUE

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(normalize4(mat),normalize3(mat),normalize2(mat))

Unit: milliseconds
             expr      min       lq   median       uq      max
1 normalize2(mat) 4.846551 5.486845 5.597799 5.861976 30.46634
2 normalize3(mat) 4.191677 4.862655 4.980571 5.153438 28.94257
3 normalize4(mat) 4.960790 5.648666 5.766207 5.972404 30.08334

set.seed(42)
mat <- matrix(sample(1:10,1e4,TRUE),10)
microbenchmark(normalize4(mat),normalize3(mat),normalize2(mat))

Unit: milliseconds
             expr      min       lq   median       uq       max
1 normalize2(mat) 4.319131 4.445384 4.556756 4.821512  9.116263
2 normalize3(mat) 5.743305 5.927829 6.098392 6.454875 13.439526
3 normalize4(mat) 3.955712 4.102306 4.175394 4.402710  5.773221
```

The `apply` solution is slightly slower if the number of columns is small, but slightly faster if the number of columns is large. Overall, performance is of the same magnitude.

Answer (score 2):

This will rescale the matrix using the same method

```
normalize <- function(x) { 
  x <- sweep(x, 2, apply(x, 2, mean))           # retrive the mean from each column
  2* sweep(x, 2, apply(x, 2, function(y) max(y)-min(y)), "/") 
}
```

}

**Edit**

use `colMeans` as suggested in comments is faster of course

```
normalize <- function(x) { 
  aa <- colMeans(x)
  x <- sweep(x, 2, aa)           # retrive the mean from each column

  2* sweep(x, 2, apply(x, 2, function(y) max(y)-min(y)), "/") 
}
A <- matrix(1:24, ncol=3)

> normalize(A)
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.0000000 -1.0000000 -1.0000000
[2,] -0.7142857 -0.7142857 -0.7142857
[3,] -0.4285714 -0.4285714 -0.4285714
[4,] -0.1428571 -0.1428571 -0.1428571
[5,]  0.1428571  0.1428571  0.1428571
[6,]  0.4285714  0.4285714  0.4285714
[7,]  0.7142857  0.7142857  0.7142857
[8,]  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000
```

**EDIT** with the `scale` function of the base package

```
scale(A,center=TRUE,scale=apply(A,2,function(x) 0.5*(max(x)-min(x))))
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -1.0000000 -1.0000000 -1.0000000
[2,] -0.7142857 -0.7142857 -0.7142857
[3,] -0.4285714 -0.4285714 -0.4285714
[4,] -0.1428571 -0.1428571 -0.1428571
[5,]  0.1428571  0.1428571  0.1428571
[6,]  0.4285714  0.4285714  0.4285714
[7,]  0.7142857  0.7142857  0.7142857
[8,]  1.0000000  1.0000000  1.0000000
```

Comment: `colMeans()` will be quicker than the first `apply()` call.

Comment: @GavinSimpson yes! you're right! I am searching how this is done in the scales packges fo example.

Comment: @GavinSimpson I think the best solution is with the scales package :)

Comment: Can't you do this with base `scale()`?

Answer (score 1):

How about just:

```
x[,1] <- (x[,1]-mean(x[,1]))/(max(x[,1])-min(x[,1]))
```

Most basic functions in `R` are vectorized, so there's no need to include a `for` loop in your code. This snippet will scale all of column 1 (you can also use the function `scale()`, although it doesn't have an option for min/max values).

To do an entire dataset, you can do something like this:

```
Scale <- function(y) y <- (y-mean(y))/(max(y)-min(y))
DataFrame.Scaled <- apply(DataFrame, 2, Scale)
```

**Edit**: It's also worth pointing out that you *don't* want to name a value after a function. When you do `min <- min(x)`, it will lead to some confusion to R the next time you ask for `min`.

Comment: Re you edit: generally good advice, but it won't cause a problem in this case; `min(foo)` will only ever match an object `min` that is a function.